# Android Recyclerview MediaPlayer previous Item sound stop, release after new one is clicked

Tags: android, audio, android-recyclerview, media-player, android-mediaplayer

In my app i have recyclerview items, and each item play sound when i click it.
Problem is that when i click few items, they all play sounds in the same time until they finish.
Lets say i click 10 items, all 10 play sounds in the same time and after some time app get crashed and i get this error: **E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)**.
I avoid app crashing by implementing automatic release with this code:

```js
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mediaPlayer.release();

                        }
                    });
```

But that's not what i want, it is annoying to hear few sounds in the same time. What i want is to stop previous sound when i click new one, i try to implent mediaplayer stop and release, but without success.

This is the app in google play so you can check by yourself: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pero.androidd.animalSoundsQuiz

Here is my Adapter code where i play sounds. In this code there is part MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() where i release sound after sound finish to aviod **E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)** error, but that is not what i want in my app. I want to stop previous sound after i click new one.

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.pero.androidd.animalsoundsforchildren.R;

import java.util.List;


public class ZivotinjeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Zivotinje> mZivotinje;


    @Override
    public ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zivotinje, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


        Zivotinje zivotinjeIme = mZivotinje.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_name());

        //THIS IS WHERE I HANDALE IMAGE VIEW. Using glide for images
        //Dohvacamo context svakog views
        ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
        Glide.with(slika_source.getContext())
                .load((Integer) zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika())
                .into(slika_source);


        viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mZivotinje.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;
        private Zivotinje mItem;



        public void setItem(Zivotinje item) {
            this.mItem = item;
        }



        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zivotinjaIme_id);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slika_id);


            //Handdaling clicks
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                        
                    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), mItem.getmSound());
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                    
                    //releace media player after sound finish
                    // BUT I DO NOT WANT TIS, I WANT TO STOP PREVIOUS SOUND WHEN I CLICK NEW ONE
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mediaPlayer.release();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }


    }


    public ZivotinjeAdapter(List<Zivotinje> animals) {
        mZivotinje = animals;
    }


}
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT:**

I find solution, i do not know is this the smartest way to do it but it works for me fine:

What i done is that i made static media player variable and this way i can  access to media player from ViewHolder and stop previous sound when i click new one. Hope it helps.

here is the whole code:

```js
public class ZivotinjeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; //THIS IS THE CHANGE I DONE

    @Override
    public ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zivotinje, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


        Zivotinje zivotinjeIme = mZivotinje.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_name());

        //THIS IS WHERE I HANDALE IMAGE VIEW. Using glide for images
        ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
        Glide.with(slika_source.getContext())
                .load((Integer) zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika())
                .into(slika_source);


        viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mZivotinje.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;
        private Zivotinje mItem;


        public void setItem(Zivotinje item) {
            this.mItem = item;
        }


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zivotinjaIme_id);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slika_id);


//handaling clicks 
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                    }


                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), mItem.getmSound());
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });

        }


    }

    private List<Zivotinje> mZivotinje;

    public ZivotinjeAdapter(List<Zivotinje> animals) {
        mZivotinje = animals;
    }


}
```

Comment: Come on guys, i need to fix this, i need help here :)

Comment: This works!!Thanks for your solution here

Answer (score 5):

You first have to check if there is a sound that is already playing and if there is, you should stop it when the user decides to start a new sound.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying ()) {
                    if (mediaplayer != null){
                        mediaplayer.stop ();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mediaplayer != null) {
                        mediaplayer.start ();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In `setOnCompletionListner` you release the sound if the user listens to the whole sound clip.

```
        mediaplayer. setOnCompletionListner (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListner () {
            public void OnCompletion (MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
                mediaplayer.release ();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes i already done something like this, the only thing i needed to do was to put static MediaPlayer varaible on the top so that i can access to media player from ViewHolder. I do not is that the smartest way to do but its wroks. Thank you for help

Comment: A perfect solution for me.