# How to use the Audio with seekbar on Recyclview android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview, android-seekbar

I am using the lists of audio on my **`Recyclview`** and it is working correct means I am able to play the audio file on my **`Recyclview`**.

As i am using the **`Seekbar`** with my audio file on my **`Recyclview`** , the problem is generating that when i am scrolling the **`Recyclview`** the other **`items's of Recyclview Seekbar`** is changing (Seekbar i am using for the progress of the audio file play.)

What i want that other **`Seekbar`** item of **`Recyclview`** sholud not be change when i scroll the **`Recyclview`**

Please check my code for it ,Inside the **`onBindViewHolder`** for my **`Recyclview`** , i am using the following code, please check it once.

```
 ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setTag(position);
            ((MyAudioChat) holder).imgPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(null);
                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setProgress(0);
                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        mediaPlayer();
                        ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer();
                        ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    }

                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.getTag();
                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()); // Set the Maximum range of the
                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());// set current progress to song's
                    Runnable moveSeekBarThread = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                                ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                                ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.setProgress(mediaPos_new);
                                ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.postDelayed(this, 100); //Looping the thread after 0.1 second
                                ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.getTag();
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
                    ((MyAudioChat) holder).sbMyAudio.postDelayed(moveSeekBarThread, 100);

                }
            });
```

I have visited the following site on **SO** but did not get the relevant solution
[1 .First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223378/play-audio-in-recyclerview)
[2. Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644981/android-recyclerview-mediaplayer-previous-item-sound-stop-release-after-new-one)

Can we use the **`setTag()`** and **`getTag()`** to get rid of from this problem. I have used the **`setTag()`** on  my above code. Please check it once.

Comment: Please help me to short out from this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although, you have asked only about correct `SeekBar` updates, I am assuming (*because you haven't shard complete source*) that soon you will face following issues which are linked to the `Adapter` implementation:

- How do I remove the seekBar updater, when `MediaPlayer` completes the playback of audio?
- How do I release the `MediaPlayer` when activity is paused?
- Anonymous `View.OnClickListener`s and `Runnable`s are being allocated on **every** `onBindViewHolder` call. How do I minimize their unnecessary allocation?

You can find complete working solution here - [GitHub](https://github.com/kujeensiti/DemoListPlayer)

Following source tries to fix all above issues. Certain data structures/classes are assumed based on your nomenclature.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        AudioChat audioChats[] = new AudioChat[128];
        rv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Arrays.asList(audioChats)));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (null != mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyAudioChat> {

        private List<AudioChat> audioChats;
        private int currentPlayingPosition;
        private SeekBarUpdater seekBarUpdater;

        MyAdapter(List<AudioChat> audioChats) {
            this.audioChats = audioChats;
            this.currentPlayingPosition = -1;
            seekBarUpdater = new SeekBarUpdater();
        }

        @Override
        public MyAudioChat onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new MyAudioChat(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyAudioChat holder, int position) {
            if (position == currentPlayingPosition) {
                seekBarUpdater.playingHolder = holder;
                holder.sbMyAudio.post(seekBarUpdater);
            } else {
                holder.sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
                holder.sbMyAudio.setProgress(0);
            }
        }

        private class SeekBarUpdater implements Runnable {
            MyAudioChat playingHolder;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (null != mediaPlayer && playingHolder.getAdapterPosition() == currentPlayingPosition) {
                    playingHolder.sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    playingHolder.sbMyAudio.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    playingHolder.sbMyAudio.postDelayed(this, 100);
                } else {
                    playingHolder.sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return audioChats.size();
        }

        class MyAudioChat extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            SeekBar sbMyAudio;
            ImageView imgPlayAudio;

            MyAudioChat(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imgPlayAudio = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayAudio);
                imgPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(this);
                sbMyAudio = (SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sbMyAudio);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPlayingPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (null != seekBarUpdater.playingHolder) {
                        seekBarUpdater.playingHolder.sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
                        seekBarUpdater.playingHolder.sbMyAudio.setProgress(0);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                seekBarUpdater.playingHolder = this;
                startMediaPlayer();
                sbMyAudio.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                sbMyAudio.post(seekBarUpdater);
            }
        }

        private void startMediaPlayer() {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mp3);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    seekBarUpdater.playingHolder.sbMyAudio.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
                    seekBarUpdater.playingHolder.sbMyAudio.setProgress(0);
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                    currentPlayingPosition = -1;
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    private class AudioChat {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for urs solution...Will let u know tomorrow..As i have stucked on the other tasks..I=My main concern is that when i scroll the recyclview (when my audio is playing with seekbar) than other items(Seekbar) also updating..Is it coovering all the things?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Yes, it covers that. Reason behind your issue is, RecyclerView re-uses views. As a result, your update listeners are updating unwanted views as well.

Comment: Plus +1 for urs effort..Will check tomorrow and let u know on it

Comment: Can we pause the audio player..Please help me on it.

Comment: Followed the GitHub demo, Really great and helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @user3161880 How to save state of an audio if it paused and played another audio.We can save state of an audio and restart from where it stopped after playing another audio in whatsapp chat.Please help.